# How do I create a Custom Action for a Workflow?

Tags: workflow, custom-actions

I need to create a Custom Action that's displayed in the Action list for a Workflow.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  SP2007 or 2010?  SPD 2007 or 2010?  Custom Action or do you mean Activity?

Answer (score 3):

There are many example of this on the Internet. Here is one of them:

[SPD 2010 Custom Workflow Activity](http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/01/spd-2010-custom-workflow-activity/)

Comment: Dead link... when you post answer, you should include part of the solution in the post, instead of a simple link, to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my question and answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/how-to-deploy-a-custom-sharepoint-workflow-activity). Hopefully that helps you too.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

2010: http://blog.furuknap.net/adding-custom-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010

2007: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kalleb/archive/2009/07/22/how-to-build-your-own-custom-action-for-sharepoint-designer-2007.aspx

Comment: I think he is talking about Custom Workflow Activities, in which case your links don't apply.