# Problem in creating custom workflow action in SharePoint

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, custom-action

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deploy a custom SharePoint Workflow Activity](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/how-to-deploy-a-custom-sharepoint-workflow-activity)

I am trying to create a custom Workflow Action for SharePoint Designer 2010. I am using Visual studio 2010 and followed the steps as mentioned in this link: http://perrystechblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/create-custom-workflow-action-in.html

But still I am not getting the created custom action in the Action list. Any solution?

Comment: Leaning towards this question being a dupe of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/16016/2070

Comment: Please see my post here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/how-to-deploy-a-custom-sharepoint-workflow-activity

Answer (score 1):

You have reconnected your SharePoint Designer to the site after you deployed it?