# "SharePoint 2013 workflow: Create a custom action" Sample does not Work

Tags: workflow, 2013

Follow the URL: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-workflow-41e5c0f9

Tried it and it can be built, but it fails in activation step:

I got the error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature
>   '2c63df2b-ceab-42c6-aeff-b3968162d4b1' for list template '4501' is not
>   installed in this farm.  The operation could not be completed.

What could it be? Are there any other workflow samples for SharePoint 2013 that actually work? It seems that this area is not well covered so far, and most of the "official" samples have some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It requires **SharePoint Server 2013** and does not work on **SharePoint Foundation**.

Comment: Oops, too bad it doesn't work with Foundation. Check out my answer here for some code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1257293/98933 or http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/how-do-i-create-a-custom-action-for-a-workflow

Comment: If you want to create SharePoint 2013 workflow action, you must have SharePoint Server 2013 installed with Workflow Manager as well. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588%28v=office.15%29#section1

Comment: Hm... after looking at that link I think you can still build actions the old fashioned way. You just won't be able to use WWF4..

Comment: Already tried that. Solution can be built and deployed, it appears in SharePoint Designer's Actions and can be inserted and populated. However, when publishing such workflow I got the error like "System.Workflow.Activities" is obsolete, and workflow fails to deploy :(

Comment: Wow good to know. Thanks for doing the investigation.

Comment: It looks like SharePoint 2010 workflows have to be built inside Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio 2012 makes these problems. This might be solution for the obsolete 2010 workflows in SP 2013.